# How to fix these weird shadowy sun rays on the spoon?

Tags: modeling

I'm quite new to modelling, and I got this pesky problem on the spoon, or maybe I shouldn't care about it? Anyways, at the bottom (same from above) we can see those rays that don't look nice, I tried lifting the faces to even it out, but no luck. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres now I usually go about solving this issue:

I start with a UV sphere with subsurf, and it has some wrinkles:

[image]

Heres what the geometry looks like:

[image: geo]

Now, i add in a smaller loop cut close to the center of the circle, making sure to position it to maintain the curvature of the sphere:

[image: cut]

Now, my wrinkles are gone, or at least imperceptible from this distance:

[image: final]

I hope this helps!

Comment: ah man I totally forgot about the loop cuts, but I've already did the subdivision surface modifier, so I guess I'll keep this in mind the next time I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you started modeling from a UV sphere, and that part used to be either the bottom or top of it, and a bunch of triangles meet there in one vertex. Or, there's an n-gon there. (guessing)

You could try to remesh the object by going into the Properties Panel > Object data Properties > Remesh, set your desired voxel size and click Remesh. It should create a nice quads only mesh for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out it only needed a simple loop cut.